# Как создать класс, который не будет выполняться программой автоматически

Tags: c#

Как создать класс, из которого будут браться только методы в другом классе? Важно чтобы этот класс не исполнялся программой.

```
namespace App
{
  class Startup
  {
  //Выполнение
  }
  class Methods
  {
  //Пропуск и выполнение функций только тогда, когда я их вызову
  }
  class Program
  {
  //Допустим, тут я вызываю функции
  }
}
```

Comment: Классы в C# и так не исполняются, может исполняться только код в функциях.

Comment: Я и имел ввиду то, чтобы все функции в классе не исполнялись

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "класс исполняется программой"?

Comment: Вангую что речь идёт об отложенной инициализации, Lazy<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все методы в C# исполняются только тогда, когда вы их вызываете.

Есть ситуации где код вызывается фреймворком, системой, но они достаточно редки, например функция `static Main` в консольном приложении.

Ваш код не может сам по себе вызываться пока вы его не вызвали, если не имеет место специальная ситуация, все возможные такие ситуации описывать в данном посте смысла нет.

В .NET нет такого что фреймворк исполняет все функции подряд.